# Using functions within differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let y be a differentiable function in $ \Bbb R$ which can be factorised as *y = f(x)·sin(x)* for some differentiable function *f(x)* in $ \Bbb R$. 
> Show that the function *y* satisfies the differential equation
> $$ y' = \Biggl[\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}
> + cot(x)\Biggr]·y $$

I am not sure how to go about approaching this problem.  I started by taking it at face value and getting $$ y' = f'(x)sin(x) + f(x)cos(x) $$ and then plugging it back into the equation.  I ended up with $$ \frac{f'(x)f'(x)sin(x)}{f(x)} + 2f'(x)cos(x) + \frac{f(x)cos(x)}{cot(x)} $$
This does not seem to be the way to go about solving the problem.

Guidance on how to solve it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y' = \Biggl[\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}
+ \cot(x)\Biggr]·y$$
$$\dfrac {y'}y -\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}
= \cot(x)$$
$$(\ln y -\ln f(x))'
= \cot(x)$$
$$(\ln \dfrac y {f(x)})'
= \cot(x)$$
Since $y=f(x)\sin x$:
$$(\ln \sin x)'
= \cot(x)$$
$$ \dfrac {\cos x} { \sin x}
= \cot(x)$$
Which is true.